# MVC metatdataprovider and html helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, metadata, html-helper

I have my own implementation of the metadataprovider, in it a check for my custom attribute and get the metadata from the database.

```
public class EntityPropertyMetadataAttribute: Attribute
{
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string EntityFullName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayFormatString { get; set; }
    public string EditFormatString { get; set; }
    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now I observed the following if I have a View like this:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
 </div>
```

The function

```
protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
```

gets called 3 times for property Id, if I remove one for example:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
 </div>
```

it gets called 2 times.
Now when I use this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)   
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>  
}
```

CreateMetadata gets called a whopping 22 for each property in the model.
That's not really what you want performance wise. Probably I should hook up the DB code (currently inside CreateMetadata method) somewhere else.

any suggestion appreciated.

cheers

Comment: What do you do with your own metadata provider?

Comment: So I can have different 'settings' for user with different roles.

Comment: Different users have depending on their group different settings when viewing data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally on the right track with a bit of help from MVC extensions
    http://mvcextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f71bcadf0e76#Trunk%2fMvcExtensions%2fModelMetadata%2fModelMetadataRegistry.cs

In my case I shouldn't override

```
 protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType,
                                                    Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
```

from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider but override the Get methods from AssociatedMetadataProvider like this one:

```
  public override IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> GetMetadataForProperties(object container, Type containerType)
```

And put hte database calls there.